# How can I print the mysql full process list to a file?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, mysql

After I run the command in mysql `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G`, it displays me a really long list of mysql processes and I'm only able to read the last 10 processes.

Is there any way I could paginate or print to file what it displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is putting all the what the command writes in your console to a file we called output.txt

```
YOURCOMMAND >> output.txt
```

nano is a text editor, you can move with the arrow-keys or page-up page-down

```
nano output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the mysql command with this switch: `--pager=less`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a decade old but the other answers were wrong then and are wrong now.  So here's a correct answer for anyone else who stumbles on this.

Create a file "processlist.sql" and inside that put:

show full processlist;

(or show full processlist \G)

Then run something like:

mysql -uroot -p < processlist.sql > out.txt

Your processlist will be dumped into the out.txt file to do with as you see fit.